# What is the motivation behind stochastic differential equations?

Tags: stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I understand the theory behind solving linear stochastic differential equations after self-teaching the topic - but what do they typically model in the real world? Is it common for stochastic differential equations to appear in many applications, particularly in finance?

Any journals or text recommendations on some (basic) examples would also be greatly appreciated.